# How to get the last current or visited Web URL in Windows?

Tags: windows, registry

I'm writing a Windows app. where you can create "links", it is easy to link files or folder (just use the standard dialogs for open files or browse folders), but for linking a Web URL I don't know how to get (from a Windows function or registry key) the current or last visited page.

Maybe something like the recently used files, but referencing web pages (independent of the browser), could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no common browser independent place to look for the last visited pages from what i know(i'm saying this from my experience at computer forensic)

I know there is a place in the registry where explorer saves this info, and probably other browsers as well, you can find this info by using a tool like procmon by sysinternals.

Just enter a site and see what the registry writes down..

Answer (score 1):

This might give you a start:

[wrapper class for URL history interface in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ponta.aspx?df=100&forumid=67589&exp=0&select=897325)

Answer (score 0):

I found it!  (at least for IE)...

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs

Then, I should find the equivalent key (or maybe a config file) of the other most common web browsers.